# What are the PHP web server architecture components and the purpose of each one of them?

Tags: web-development, php, architecture, web-servers

Given below is an image of a basic PHP web server architecture:

[image: PHP web server architecture]

Would someone please explain the several components available and how they interact?
I'm more concerned of how the **PHP Core** operates and relates to the other components, so feel free to elaborate on this point specifically.

This Diagram was taken from [here](http://talks.php.net/presentations/slides/intro/php4_arch.gif).

Comment: You'll need to clarify: 1) What do you mean by PHP core functions, 2) What _exactly_ you are asking. Also, what's the source of the image?

Comment: Isn't PHP open-source? You might want to look at the code and then if you don't understand, ask specific questions about what is unclear to you.

Comment: Please check the Updated question

Comment: I am not concerned about the code of PHP, here I am focussed on PHP as a whole, I need to know What makes the PHP Run

Comment: @OMTheEternity "What makes the PHP Run" doesn't really make much sense. I understand there's a language barrier here, but you really need to try harder. Also, when I asked for the source of the image, I meant the presentation, linking to the image itself doesn't really help.

Comment: @YannisRizos  I was asked by an interviewer by showing the PHP Web Server Architecture.. That what is operating PHP in this architecture.. How does PHP works internally, with its ini, kibraries, interpretators and other extensions.... I was blank... to answer it... May be i dont know what is being asked

Comment: @OMTheEternity Ok then, [this presentation](http://www.comp.rgu.ac.uk/staff/fh/CMM007/Lectures/ServerSideScripting3.pdf) might help clarify things a bit.

Comment: @YannisRizos Thanks for sharing but i already reffered it... But didnt got any help from it as this PDF explains the PHP-Web Architecture NOT the PHP Core specificaLLY..

Comment: @YannisRizos great presentation, but I think the OP wants its explanation :)

Comment: @Songo I need to understand the question before I can answer it. Unfortunately I still haven't understood exactly what is being asked here.

Comment: @YannisRizos well, once in an interview I had a somewhat similar question where the interviewer asked me this "What are the PHP web server architecture components? what's the purpose of each one of them and How do they interact?" :D I think this may be a suitable title for this question :)

Comment: @Songo Then please _edit it_. And if you feel you have a good answer, go for it!

Comment: I'm too busy on better things, but this is very simple. Download the source code of PHP and see the relevant folders such as sapi, zend (for the engine), core, and other. Write a sample PECL module in C for PHP and you will get a good understanding of how it works. The internals of Zend Engine are undocumented, as you will find no comments in the code, but the rest of PHP is very simple to grasp. See the SAPI header files to start.

Answer (score 1):

Very roughly:

- SAPI transfers (and translates) the data received by the http daemon (but not necessarily only it, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Application_Programming_Interface)) to the PHP framework
- PHP Core is the "basic" functionality provided by the language (e.g. what allows you to use `echo $variable`)
- PHP API is additional functionality you can use to access separate services (e.g. a database) - the exact line between those two is a bit fuzzy (imho)
- ZEND is the engine that actually executes the PHP scripts (compiler and runtime environment) - see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Engine) again.

Comment: As I understand it, **PHP API is the functionality you get through the extensions**: `mbstring`, `PDO`, `APC`, `Streams`, etc., and **PHP core is everything else**, i.e. everything available in native PHP with no extensions. I'm not editing the answer since I'm not sure if my understanding is correct.

Comment: I think that's right, but I'm not a PHP guru. For me this is really fuzzy since many of the extensions are bundled with PHP by default.